# JFrame and JOptionPane

Tags: java, jframe, joptionpane

I have been messing around for a bit now to get this to work how I intend it to work, but couldn't find anything through Google or API to find the answer I seek, so here I am!

The project I am currently working on is an App for soldier registration (Theme of project), I used `JFrame` and `JButton`s, but I need to get a dialog box in `JFrame` that will intake answers. Something that works like this, but is integrated in `JFrame`:

```
nameField = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Username(Default is 000000");
```

Comment: mostly you can refer to it by using the word `this` ín case that you are writing it in the `JFrame class` where you want it to appear

Comment: Why not just add a panel with some buttons?  There are many ways to lay out such a panel;  we would need to see your user interface to advise how to do so.  You could also place your user interface in a JDesktopPane and use one of the JOptionPane.showInternal methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, by integrated into JFrame, I'm not quite sure what you want the dialog to do, but by simply setting the first parameter in `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` to the parent frame, the input will have the icon of the parent window.

```
nameField = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(myParentFrame,"Enter Username(Default is 000000");
```

Comment: I think my explanation was poor, I will try to explain what I mean better now.

Comment: So, JOptionPane is making a new window where I can input the values I want and then take them back by making the whole line equal to the String, Like in code line above, but what I want is so that there was the same input line but without a bonus window, is this even possible? If so, could you link me an API for it?

Comment: @Avendril Of course you could just add a `JTextField`. But if you haven't already, I really suggest installing [window builder](https://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/). It makes it so that you don't have to write out the design of your application.